# How to generate a random number in a swtich in c++

Tags: c++, random

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
srand(time(0));
char computerChoice;
switch ( rand()%3)
    {
        case 0:
            computerChoice = 'R';
        case 1:
            computerChoice = 'P';
        case 2:
            computerChoice = 'S';
    }
cout << computerChoice;
}
```

I keep getting 'S' for computerChoice each time the program is run and if I loop the program I keep getting 'S' still.

Comment: Prefer the `<random>` header. Also, I imagine your compiler might tell you the problem with a higher warning level.

Comment: I don't always advocate writing less code, but in this case I think it's warranted -- `char computerChoice = "RPS"[rand()%3];`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Love it. Simple and elegant. Might want a comment explaining it, though :)

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You have to `break;` after each `case` statement. See [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting the same answer because you forgot the break statement, i.e

```
switch ( rand()%3)
{
    case 0:
        computerChoice = 'R';
        break;
    case 1:
        computerChoice = 'P';
        break;
    case 2:
        computerChoice = 'S';
        break;
}
```

}